# Weird behaviour leaflet and Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet

I have a shiny app which uses the leaflet library. 
I need now to use the `get.Bounds()` function to get some coordinates. Easy enough (`js file`):

```
var myBounds = map.getBounds();
console.log(myBounds);
```

Then I need to send the coordinates to shiny for further processing (also in my `js file`:

```
Shiny.onInputChange("bounds", myBounds);
```

To see if that worked, it did in the `server.R` this:

```
observe({
  print(input$bounds)
})
```

However, when I run the app in the **R** console appears `NULL`. Through the `console.log` in my `.js file` the coordinates are printed in the **Firefox** console.

BUT, it works every now and then. When I run the Shiny App ten times, it works sometimes three times, sometimes four times and sometimes never. I get the coordinates and they get printed into the **R** console.

I tried with `reactive` too, but that dod not do the trick. Same behaviour here.

```
#get extensions of map
  myBoundsR <- reactive({
  input$bounds
 })
#print extensions
observe(print(myBoundsR()))
```

Why is that?! Why is the behaviour that inconsequent?! Why doesnt the line `Shiny.onInputChange("bounds", myBounds);` send the coordinates to `server.R`?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change it like this:

```
 map.on('moveend', function(e) {
 var myBounds = map.getBounds();
 Shiny.onInputChange("bounds", myBounds);
 console.log(myBounds);
 });
```

It might be the problem that the extends of the window are not send for the "starting window"?! Thats just a guess though. I cannt find anything on that. And since the `js` is only gone through once, from top to bottom, the code only gets executed once. 
Writing it this way, it should work when you pan/zoom?!

Let me know if that helped you!

Comment: That works better now. Every now and then I stell get a `NULL` value. However, that occurs pretty rare.